# How to change Python to Apps Script get api?

Tags: javascript, python, json, api, google-apps-script

I want to change python to apps script in apps script have UrlFetchApp function i'm never use but i'm try
I have code python can get api normally

```
import requests
 
url = "https://api.aiforthai.in.th/ssense"
 
text = 'Have a good day'
 
params = {'text':text}
 
headers = {
    'Apikey': "xxx-xxx-xxx"
    }
 
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
 
print(response.json())
```

so now i'm try code apps script like this but notthing came out ;
Api dashboard call me i'm use api.
maybe wrong payload text?

Detail API

- Host
  https://api.aiforthai.in.th/ssense
- Method
  GET/POST
- Header
  Apikey : xxx-xxx-xxx
  Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- Parameter
  text : text for analysis

This my wrong apps script code

```
function call_api() {
  var url = "https://api.aiforthai.in.th/ssense"

  var apiKey = "xxx-xxx-xxx";

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    url,
    {
      "headers": {
        "Apikey": apiKey,
        "text": "Have a good day"
      }
    }
  )
  Logger.log(response)
}
```

Thank you for solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to convert the following python script to Google Apps Script.

  ```
    import requests

    url = "https://api.aiforthai.in.th/ssense"

    text = 'Have a good day'

    params = {'text':text}

    headers = {
        'Apikey': "xxx-xxx-xxx"
        }

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)

    print(response.json())
  ```
- You have already been confirmed that your python script worked fine.

When I saw your python script, `text` is sent as the query parameter. In this case, how about the folloiwng modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function call_api2() {
  var text = "Have a good day";
  var url = `https://api.aiforthai.in.th/ssense?text=${encodeURIComponent(text)}`;
  var apiKey = "xxx-xxx-xxx";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    url,
    { "headers": { "Apikey": apiKey } }
  );
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

#### Note:

- If you test the above modified script, when an error occurs, please confirm your `apiKey` again.
- If an error like status code 403 occurs, your URL might not be able to be requested from Google side. I'm worried about this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
function call_api() {
  var url = "https://api.aiforthai.in.th/ssense";

  var apiKey = "xxx-xxx-xxx";

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    url,
    {
      "method" : "GET",
      "headers" : {
        "Apikey" : apiKey,
        "text" : "Have a good day"
      }
    }
  );
  Logger.log(response)
}
```

You can check out the UrlFetchApp [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) for future reference.

Comment: can run and call api but not show anything

Comment: @wato What is the output when running your Python code? And do you have any documentation related to the API you're trying to interact with?

Comment: json pattern , that's sure i have doc api but doc have tutorial python no one apps script and i try call in apps script because i try call with python it's work T_T // If your have new method can you tell me because i will call api in google sheet and import data to google data studio. Thank you sir